# Creating a for loop in my bash script

Tags: ubuntu

I have a pretty simply script. I just want to cd in various directories that look something like this:

```
cd PKA1/timestep_size/v_0.001/250eV
../ovitos silica_defects.py
```

I would like to loop through PKA1 to PKA24 in increments of 1. How can I do this? Also, is there a way to apply silica_defects.py to each directory and have it output the file there, as opposed to copying silica_defects.py to each subfolder (the 250eV subfolders).

Answer (score 2):

It's a job for `bash`'s brace expansion, `{START..END}`:

```
PKA{1..24}
```

So you can do:

```
for f in PKA{1..24}/timestep_size/v_0.001/250eV/; do ...; done
```

And for the `silica_defects.py`, use absolute path to the file.

Comment: I also need to cd to those, does the way you wrote it do that?

Comment: @JacksonHart Refer the variable: `cd "$f"`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I just see that the code says, that silica_defects.py could not be opened. i have the right path, not sure why it wont open.

Comment: Also, If silica file references other files, do they take the path from where I am, or where the bash script currently is operating in?

Comment: the problem is that silica_defects.py references a file in those directories called cascade.dump. defeats the purpose if I have to go through and say the exact path of those

Answer (score 1):

Let's use a for-loop to generate the integers 1 through to 24, use `cd` in a subshell to change directory to the subdirectories, and execute the script:

```
for (( i = 1; i <= 24; ++i )); do
  ( cd "PKA$i/timestep_size/v_0.001/250eV" && ../ovitos /path/to/silica_defects.py )
done
```

By using a subshell, you avoid having to "change back" to an old directory before using `cd` for the next subdirectory.  With `&&`, you also avoid trying to run the program if the directory for some reason doesn't exist.

Obviously, you could also do

```
for i in {1..24}; do
  ( cd "PKA$i/timestep_size/v_0.001/250eV" && ../ovitos /path/to/silica_defects.py )
done
```

... but I don't like the `{start..end}` syntax for aesthetic reasons, and it also doesn't give you the opportunity to be more flexible with how you want do the loop (in other situations).

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem with:

```
for ((i=1;i<=24;i++)) ; do
    cd PKA${i}/timestep_size/v_0.001/250eV
    ../ovitos silica_defects.py
    cd $OLDPWD
done
```

Comment: Based on the question, the `silica_defects.py` file is not there so it would need to be referenced properly (correct path).